# 'wordItem' object has no attribute 'len',django,python

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making word counter by using django.
↓this is views

```
def count(request):
    counter = wordItem(content = request.POST['content'])
    word_wow = counter.len()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('word', {'jcole':word_wow})
```

↓this is models

```
class wordItem(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

↓this is templates

```
  <body>
<hr><br>
    <center>
     {% for all_content in all_contents %}
     {{ all_content.content }}
     {%endfor%}
     <form action="/wow" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input style="width:500px; height:300px;" maxlength="100" type="text" name="content"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Count"/>
```

I also add path in urls.
However, I was given AttributeError: 'wordItem' object has no attribute 'len'
this error.

Comment: You likely do something in the template that raises the error... Please share the parts of the template where you use `all_contents` *and* elements of `all_contents`.

Comment: Is counter a string? In which case len(counter) is what you need. Or print it to see what it is.